# Nested maps in Go

Tags: go

In Javascript I'd do something like this:

```
var funcName = function(param1, param2, param3) {
    return {
        arr: [
           {key1: param1, key2: param2}
        ],
        key2: param3
    };
}
```

What would be the equivalent in Go?

Comment: Equivalent to do what exactly?

Comment: To write a function just like the one above @JimB

Comment: Now it makes a little more sense. Normally in Go you would define a type to return. Can you show what you're trying to solve? You can use `map[string]interface{}` and `[]interface{}`, but that's usually not that useful.

Comment: I want to parse it to json in order to send a request @JimB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a direct translation to Go:

```
var funcName = func(param1, param2, param3 interface{}) interface{} {
  return map[string]interface{}{
    "arr": []interface{}{
        map[string]interface{}{"key1": param1, "key2": param2},
    },
    "key2": param3,
  }
}
```

There's probably a better way to accomplish the real problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're trying to end up with a JSON that looks like this:

```
{
    "arr": [{
        "key1": <param1>,
        "key2": <param2>
    }],
    "key2": <param3>
}
```

Is that accurate?  If so, it's far easier in Go to just define a data structure that matches, like:

```
struct {
    Arr  []map[string]interface{} `json:"arr"`
    Key2 interface{}              `json:"key2"`
}
```

You can then directly marshal to JSON using the built in `json` package.  Example: https://play.golang.org/p/GE9DV1QeDC